# mongodb aggrecation lookup return every item in collection

Tags: mongodb

I want to lookup two collections using mongodb with aggregate, this is my query :

```
db.getCollection('buddies').aggregate([
{
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "users",
         localField: "ObjectId(userId)",
         foreignField: "ObjectId(_id)",
         as: "user_buddy"
       }
  }
])
```

the problem is I use userId to aggregate it. `users` collection and `buddies` collection is **1 to 1**.

I wish it will add `user_buddy` property matched by buddies.userId and users._id, but what I got is different :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b3a2fca0fe843093879b5bc"),
    "isVerified" : false,
    "isActivated" : false,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-07-02T13:59:05.273Z"),
    "userId" : "5b2deca18966a405412d1266",
    "phone" : "+6239109301",
    "photo" : "https://cloudinary.com",
    "idCardType" : "KTP",
    "idNumber" : "19901390193019",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-07-02T13:59:05.273Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "user_buddy" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b2dec013efecd0514a50561"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-06-23T06:43:11.092Z"),
            "username" : "lalaland",
            "email" : "lalaland@gmail.com",
            "fullname" : "Lala Princess",
            "nickname" : "lala",
            "password" : "$2a$08$LUs3fW/YPzkQeHvqH7QvTOr5H8RgqTGVvldFcUHFcfBGoRs.jn0hS",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-06-23T06:43:11.092Z"),
            "__v" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b2deca18966a405412d1266"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-06-23T06:45:48.578Z"),
            "username" : "yozawiratama",
            "email" : "yoza@yahoo.com",
            "fullname" : "Yoza Extra",
            "nickname" : "Yoza",
            "password" : "$2a$08$uZ/G61qtqdlSgSz.Qzt/i.ufiUBoPq7H8ViVwlJ1pA9SUZYUp34sO",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-06-23T06:45:48.578Z"),
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

as you can see userid of buddies is **5b2deca18966a405412d1266**, but in `user_buddy` return two documents, and one of them have different `_id`

I wish it will match `buddies.userId` and `users._id`.

how to solve this?

Comment: your `userId` is string... Convert it to mongoose ObjectId

Comment: do you mean when I insert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localField` and `foreignField` are field names.

Should be

```
db.getCollection('buddies').aggregate([
{
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "users",
         localField: "userId",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "user_buddy"
       }
  }
])
```

without "ObjectId"

ObjectId should be in the document itself:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b3a2fca0fe843093879b5bc"),
    "isVerified" : false,
    "isActivated" : false,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-07-02T13:59:05.273Z"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("5b2deca18966a405412d1266")
    ....
```